# Cannot connect to VMWARE

Tags: windows-7

I am now working in Hungary,  but I need a USA ip address for work.  No Problem.....
Using  ExpressVPN I can then connect to my work VPN ( https://agevpn.arisevendor.net/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi )
but then I cannot connect to my remote server (arise.mydesktop.agero.com)  .  "Unable to connect"   Using Windows 7.   When I am in the USA, I don't have this problem. 
  Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you use the same laptop in the USA to RDP into the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways to troubleshoot or resolve the issue:

1. Can we ping the remote server?
   Try using the following command: ping IP(the IP address of the remote server)

If ping is successful, the network connection between the two places is no problem. If ping is failed, maybe there is a problem with the network, try to check the network in two places.

2. Check if the remote server port of 3389 is open? 
   Check if the remote machine's port 3389 is open, use the following command: telnet IP(the IP address of the remote server) 3389

[image]

If we can ping, but the port of 3389 is not open in any place, there may be something that limits the port. This problem could indicate that another application on the remote server is using the same TCP port as the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). The default port assigned to RDP is 3389.

3. Check the **Remote Desktop Service** in remote service is started.

The startup type: **Automatic**

The service status: **started**

[image]

4. We can’t connect to a computer that's asleep or hibernating, so make sure the settings for sleep and hibernation on the remote computer are set to Never.
5. Did we use the same machine in the USA and in Hungary to RDP into the remote server? we can't use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to a computer using Windows 7 Starter, Windows 7 Home Basic, or Windows 7 Home Premium.
6. To verify that Remote Desktop is enabled.
7. Ensure the **logon user** is a member of the Remote Desktop Users group.

For details we can refer the article: [Remote Desktop disconnected or can’t connect to remote computer or Remote Desktop server (Terminal Server) that is running Windows Server 2008](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2477133/remote-desktop-disconnected-or-can-t-connect-to-remote-computer-or-rem)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  However, if I understand it correctly,  it is not your standard remote desktop, it is a VMWARE server that I cannot connect to.  Yes, it worked fine on the same computer when I was in the States last week.  I can connect to my company VPN just fine ( as long as I use another VPN first to get a USA ipaddress),  But that's as far as I can go.  Is there a different / better VPN that I should try?